# MATLAB unable to create connection between two MATLAB sessions

Tags: matlab, session, network-programming, tcp

I am new to MATLAB, and am working on my Engineering Final Year Project. I want to create a TCP/IP session where I send data between a server session and a client session.

The code for my server session:

```
data = (1:10);
t = tcpip('localhost', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
fwrite(t, data);
```

The code for my client session:

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
fopen(t);
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
disp(data);
```

I opened two MATLAB Windows and ran them both, server first. The server program kept running with no connection to the client:

```
>> tcpserver
```

And the client program gave an error:

```
>> tcpclient
Error using icinterface/fread (line 163)
SIZE must be greater than 0.

Error in tcpclient (line 3)
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
```

Comment: Did you try using `0.0.0.0` for the server and `localhost` for the client? To me it seems like it's the wrong way round...

Comment: @dasdingonesin Thanks! that worked.... now I am having issue with my real task.... I am creating a new post. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the IP addresses the wrong way round. You need

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
```

on your server-side MATLAB instance and

```
t = tcpip('localhost', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
```

on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the reason. It was due to synchronization issues. The client and server weren't waiting for each other.
Server Code:

```
data=(1:10);
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
pause(1);
fwrite(t, data);
```

Client Code:

```
t = tcpip('localhost', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
fopen(t);
while t.BytesAvailable == 0
    pause(1)
end
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
disp(data);
fclose(t);
delete(t);
clear t;
```

Server Response:

```
>> tcpserver
```

Client Response:

```
>> tcpclient
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

Cheers!